# What is the difference between the following ways to empty files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, filesystems

Assume the file name to be emptied is foo, the common ways to empty files are shown below. I want to know the difference between them, such as performance, I/O pressure to the system and etc.

```sh
#1 also ":>foo" and "true>foo" 
echo > foo

#2
dd if=/dev/null of=foo

#3
cp /dev/null >foo

#4
cat /dev/null >foo

#5
truncate -s 0 foo
```

Comment: What did you find out by reading the manual for each command? What is unclear? (I'm voting to close the question until you specify the problem)

Comment: What do you personally expect from `cat /dev/null foo` for example?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I wanna know not only how to use these commands but also the something behind the commands, such as performance. I'll edit my question to specify.

Comment: Use commands as they seem fit. There are more commands than people in this world so picking random commands doesn't do any good. _Why_ did you choose these? Why use them the way you did?

Comment: @TedLyngmo It should be "cat /dev/null >foo", I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say much about this that won't depend on the OS you're using, which shell and implementation of various utilities you have, etc. That said, forking subprocesses is often one of the slower/more computationally expensive things for a shell script to do, so if you want to optimize for performance, you should minimize the number of processes your script creates.

On that basis, `: >foo` and `true >foo` are probably the best choices, because the POSIX standard requires shells to implement them as builtins, meaning that the shell will "execute" it directly without needing to fork a subprocess.

Many shells also implement `echo` as a builtin, but that actually doesn't empty the file, it writes a single newline character to it.

All of the other commands on your list are generally external, so they require an expensive process fork. The computational expense of that is likely to dwarf anything about how the I/O to the file is done.

(Oh, and `cat /dev/null foo` should probably be `cat /dev/null >foo`.)

Comment: Thanks. I think I should not focus too much on tricks in shell. Another question is: Does  "''>echo" have same performance compared to ": >foo" or "true >foo"?

Comment: @付昊天 In shells that implement `echo` as a builtin (which most shells do), it should perform about the same as `:` and `true`. But as I said, it does write something into the file.